# Error while using webpack to compile jsx and js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use koajs and reactjs to make a boilerplate application, to use later as a starting point for projects.

I am trying to use webpack as a means to compile my react jsx files, but I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/js/index.js 5:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import App from "./components/App";
| 
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    loader: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader", 
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/src/js'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    }
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: write here your App js file codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader", 
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/src/js'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I got the same error, after changing this, unfortunately.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Changed loaders to module. I have a similar setup which works fine.

Comment: Now I am getting another error: ERROR in ./src/js/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Couldn't find preset "@babel/preset-env" relative to directory "/home/user/Desktop/dir/app"

Comment: npm i --save @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react

Comment: After adding those and reinstalling dependencies, there was some version conflict, but now its fixed. Thank you for helping me :D